# Can a Remote Desktop Client share a local network connection to the Remote Desktop Host?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, local-area-network, nic

I know it is possible to share a client's local resources with a remote desktop host.

Is it also possible to share a client's local NIC with the host server, over remote desktop, with the host?

The specific scenario I have in mind is where a user would user their on-board NIC (or USB NIC) to physically access Network A, then simultaneously connect via Wi-Fi to Network B where they could RDP into a Host server running an Application.  I would like the Host server's application on Network B to be able to communicate, through the client, to Network A.

I've attached an image to clarify.

[Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXMQZ.jpg)

More details (Edit):
Normally, the hosted application would have access over the enterprise network to the devices which it needs to connect.  However, there are"stand-alone" systems not connected to the enterprise network that I'd like the application to access.  The engineer would bring their laptop to the equipment, plug-in locally, RDP to the application server, and share the local NIC.

Traditionally, this was done with a local VM running on the user's laptop, but our IT department is reluctant to allow users to have VMs, and I wanted to see if there was a way to do this over RDP in order to control access.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: That's what I thought.
Would this be possible using vSphere or other VM service, to pass-through the NIC?

Comment: @joeqwerty Can you please explain why ? Give some explanations ?

Comment: I don't know why Microsoft didn't make this possible, so I can't explain why. If you want an explanation you should ask Microsoft.